# How to solve the error "iteration limit reached without convergence"?

Tags: error-handling

For growth curve modeling in R, I need to calculate these two models:

````
Model2 <- lme(action~time, random=~1+time|ID, data=school_l[is_not_nan, ])``` 

Model1 works well but for Model2 I receive the following error message: 

```Error in lme.formula(action ~ time, random = ~1 + time | ID, data = school_l[is_not_nan,  : nlminb problem, convergence error code = 1 ; message = iteration limit reached without convergence (10)```

What did I wrong, what can I do to fix it? 
(I didn't manage to solve it on my own with just googling or having a look on related questions)
````

Comment: You should start asking yourself why people are not responding to this Q and several others of yours. I suspect it's because most experienced respondents can see immediately that the question does not have sufficient information to answer it.

Comment: Actually some respondents were just not living in the same city or even in the same country anymore when the second or third measurement wave took place. But yes, I should definitely have a look at this, too, thanks. I'm not sure if this is what you mean though.. To be honest, I don't fully understand why this is important for the iterations error, but this might be due to my lack in understanding of the error message